# Hola, tengo un problema, ¿por qué mi variable "int count" vuelve a 0 al salir de mi funcion "load_data"?

Tags: c++

Tengo un problema, ¿Por qué mi variable `int count` vuelve a 0 al salir de mi función `load_data`? causando que al usar `order_view_data` me muestre solo el primer dato del array.

Verifiqué que esto es así con un `cout << count << endl;` al inicio del `for` en `order_view_data` y como pueden ver en ningún momento yo manualmente le asigno valor 0 a `count`.

¿Estoy haciendo algo mal? ¿Cómo lo puedo arreglar?

```
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

struct student
{
    string name;
    string lastname;
};

const int x = 100;
student students[100];
int menu, menu1, count;

void load_data(struct student students[100], int count);
void order_view_data(struct student students[100], int count);
void request_data(struct student students[100], int count);

int main()
{
    do
    {
        load_data(students, count); //cargar datos de nuestro txt...

        cout << "1. Mostrar listado de los alumnos en pantalla." << endl;
        cout << "2. Mostrar un alumno determinado." << endl;
        cout << "3. Insertar un alumno a la lista." << endl;
        cout << "4. Eliminar un alumno de la lista." << endl;
        cout << "5. Buscar un alumno." << endl;
        cout << endl;
        cout << "0. Salir." << endl;
        cout << endl;
        cout << " -> ";
        cin >> menu;
        cin.ignore();
        cout << endl;

        switch(menu)
        {
            case 1:

            order_view_data(students, count);

            break;
            case 3:

            if(count < 100) //si contador es menor al maximo de alumnos...
            {
                request_data(students, count); //pedir y guardar los datos.
            }

            break;
            case 0:

            cout << "El programa se esta cerrando..." << endl;

            break;
            default:

            cout << "No se ingreso una opcion valida. Vuelva a intentar" << endl;
        }
    }while(menu!=0);

    cin.get();

    return 0;
}

void load_data(struct student students[100], int count)
{
    ifstream imp_file;
    imp_file.open("students.txt", ios::in);
    if(imp_file.is_open())
    {
        while(!imp_file.eof())
        {
            getline(imp_file, students[count].name);

            getline(imp_file, students[count].lastname);

            if( (!students[count].name.empty()) && (!students[count].lastname.empty()) ) //si ambos campos no estan vacios...
            {
                count++; //cambiar de posicion.
            }
        }
    }
    imp_file.close();
}

void order_view_data(struct student students[100], int count)
{
    for (int i = 0; i<=count; i++)
    {
        cout << count << endl;
        cout << students[i].name << " " << students[i].lastname << endl;
    }

    cout << endl;
}

void request_data(struct student students[100], int count)
{
    cout << "Ingrese el/los nombre/s del alumno: ";
    getline(cin, students[count].name);
    cout << "Ingrese el/los apellido/s del alumno: ";
    getline(cin, students[count].lastname);

    ofstream oup_file;
    oup_file.open("students.txt", ios::app);
    if(oup_file.is_open())
    {
        oup_file << students[count].name << endl;
        oup_file << students[count].lastname << endl;
    }
    oup_file.close();

    count++;
}
```

Comment: ¿ Todo esa cantidad de código es necesario para reproducir tu problema ? ¿ **Todo** ? Deberías consultar lo que es un [mcve]. Un saludo.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: Lo que le pasas a la funcion es una copia de la variable, no la variable en si. Tienes que pasarla por referencia o como un puntero.

Comment: Para complementar lo que dice @Pablochaches, léete este pequeño artículo: https://julioecheverri.wordpress.com/2015/01/29/paso-de-variables-por-referencia-en-c/

Comment: Dale, muchas gracias, lo leeré atentamente! gracias por molestarse

Comment: @Kenko Amigo, no es obligatorio pero es una recomendacion de mi parte. Si vas a modificar la variable, te recomiendo que la pases por puntero. Asi es claro que vas a modificar la variable para cualquier lector. De otro modo se espera que la pases por referencia constante.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ¿por que mi variable int count vuelve a 0 al salir de mi función load_data?

Porque la variable que le pasas a la función se la facilitas **por valor**, es decir, haces una copia de tu variable y la función trabaja con esa copia... es como si clonas a Dolly y te cargas al clon... misteriosamente la Dolly original sigue viviendo ...

Para evitar este contratiempo puedes usar referencias:

```
void load_data(struct student students[100], int & count)
//                                               ^ ahora count es una referencia
```